# forward filtered email from _different_ account in TB

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-forwarding

I have two accounts set up in ThunderBird, say acc1@example.com and acc2@test.org

I created a filter to forward all incoming messages to acc2@test.org to a couple addresses. Thunderbird attempts to send them from acc2@test.org (and fails because of email forwarding policies at that server). Therefore, I would like those messages to be sent **from acc1@example.com**.

I haven't found a way to achieve this, if at all possible.
I'd appreciate any hint on how to do it.

Thunderbird 38.5.1 running under windows 8.1

Comment: This question would be better suited to http://superuser.com/ as it deals with general purpose software, not programming-related.